How to mine on a POS private network
For testing purposes, I source-installed go-ethereum and built a private network.
After setting up the genesis.json file, I successfully created a private network, but I don't know how to mine the current block that has been converted to PoS.
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 5846471,
    "terminalTotalDifficultyPassed": true
  },
  "difficulty": "1",
  "gasLimit": "8000000",
  "extradata": "",
  "alloc": {}
}

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs
The site only explains how to mine based on PoW.
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-miner
The site says that the miner command is currently deprecated.
Please let me know how to mine on PoS or if there is a site that explains it.

you need a beacon client (prysm, lighthouse etc) AND validators. In PoS, there's no miners. Instead you have validators who verify other people's transactions and earn crypto money in exchange for correctly and honestly verifying transactions.

IMO mining on a private PoS network isn't possible because mining is inherently a PoW process.

Here is a page named proof-of-stake-devnet from prysm `s doc.
explain how to use prysm to achieve your goal , and can set balance of you account for testing purpose.
